# Using nvv4l2camerasrc to get data from a virtual device created by v4l2loopback

Tags: v4l2loopback

Is there a way to use nvv4l2camerasrc to get data stream from a virtual device created by v4l2loopback ?
Up to now, I just could stream video from a virtual device by following those steps:

- Create a virtual device using one of those pipelines:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! 'video/x-raw' ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video2
```

or

```
gst-launch-1.0 nvv4l2camerasrc device=/dev/video0 ! 'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), format=UYVY' ! nvvidconv ! identity drop-allocation=true ! queue ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video2
```

- And then create a pipeline for streaming like this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video2 ! 'video/x-raw' ! fpsdisplaysink video-sink=fakesink text-overlay=0 sync=false -v
```

However, I would like to use a pipeline with nvv4l2camerasrc for streaming but it hasn't worked yet:

```
gst-launch-1.0 nvv4l2camerasrc device=/dev/video2 ! 'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), format=UYVY' ! nvvideoconvert ! fpsdisplaysink video-sink=fakesink --verbose
```